# Why do animals have more heavy nitrogen and carbon than plants?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, zoology

> There are two stable Isotopes of nitrogen N14 and N15. The ratio of
>   15N/14N tends to increase with trophic level, such that herbivores
>   have higher nitrogen isotope values than plants, and carnivores have
>   higher nitrogen isotope values than herbivores. Depending on the
>   tissue being examined, there tends to be an increase of 3-4‰ at each
>   trophic level.
>
> The tissues and hair of vegans therefore contain significantly lower
>   percentage of 15N than the bodies of people who eat mostly meat.
>   Isotopic analysis of hair is an important source of information for
>   archaeologists, providing clues about the ancient diets.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopic_signature#Nitrogen_isotopes

But how does N14 'disappear' from plant to animal?

Comment: Your last line does not seem to match the rest of the question as you did not say anything about N-14 'disappearing' anywhere else in the question. Yet, herbivores have more N-15 than plants and carnivores have more N-15 than herbivores because of bioaccumulation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioaccumulation). This claim is also supported by @Roland's answer.

Answer (score 8):

Organisms accumulate certain isotopes because their metabolic enzymes have a slight preference for molecules containing that isotope. A well-known example is ribulose-1,5-bisphosphate carboxylase (Rubisco) which is responsible for CO$_2$ fixation in photosynthetic plants: this enzyme is somewhat more efficient with $^{12}$CO$_2$ than with $^{13}$CO$_2$, causing plants to accumulate $^{12}$C.

In animals, there is an enrichment for $^{15}$N because the deaminases and transaminases that transfer nitrogen from amino acids to urea (for excretion) tend to favor $^{14}$N. So in this case, $^{14}$N tends to be removed from the body faster than $^{15}$N when breaking down dietary protein. The differences are very small though: the relative enrichment of about 0.4% per trophic level corresponds to 0.367% $^{15}$N in a herbivore, compared to 0.366% $^{15}$N in a plant.

Source: [this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9683412).